# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'move'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm creating a rock, paper, scissors game for my class. Used the 
         'Int(input object to select a CPU strategy, but now it wont allow 
         the CPU to pass a move after I throw mine once we are in the round. 
         Please help.

The error in GitBash:
         Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "rps.py", line 171, in 
         Game.play_single()
         File "rps.py", line 123, in play_single
         self.play_round()
         File "rps.py", line 86, in play_round
         move2 = self.p2.move()

How can I correct this traceback error?

Here is my code:

```
def __init__(self, p2):
    self.p1 = HumanPlayer()
    self.p2 = p2

def play_round(self):
    move1 = self.p1.move()
    move2 = self.p2.move()
    print(f"Player 1: {move1} <> Player 2: {move2}")
    self.p1.learn(move1, move2)
    self.p2.learn(move2, move1)
    if beats(move1, move2):
        self.p1_score += 1
        print('* Player 1 wins! *')
    else:
        if move1 == move2:
            print('* Tie *')
        else:
            self.p2_score += 1
            print('* Player 2 wins! *')

    print(f"Player:{self.p1.__class__.__name__}, Score:{self.p1_score}")
    print(f"Player:{self.p2.__class__.__name__}, Score:{self.p2_score}")

# This will call a tourney
def play_game(self):
    print("Game Start!")
    for round in range(3):
        print(f"Round {round}:")
        self.play_round()
    if self.p1_score > self.p2_score:
        print('** Congrats! Player 1 WINS! **')
    elif self.p2_score > self.p1_score:
        print('** Sadly Player 2 WINS! **')
    else:
        print('** The match was a tie! **')
    print('The final score is: ' + str(self.p1_score) + ' TO ' +
          str(self.p2_score))
    print("Game over!")

# This will call a singe game.
def play_single(self):
    print("Single Game Start!")
    print(f"Round 1 of 1:")
    self.play_round()
    if self.p1_score > self.p2_score:
        print('** Congrats! Player 1 WINS! **')
    elif self.p1_score < self.p2_score:
        print('** Sadly Player 2 WINS! **')
    else:
        print('** The game was a tie! **')
    print('The final score: ' + str(self.p1_score) + ' TO ' +
          str(self.p2_score))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p2 = {
        "1": Player(),
        "2": RandomPlayer(),
        "3": CyclePlayer(),
        "4": ReflectPlayer()
        }

# Selecting Opponent
while True:
    try:
        p2 = int(input("Select the strategy "
                       "you want to play against:  "
                       "1 - Rock Player "
                       "2 - Random Player "
                       "3 - Cycle Player "
                       "4 - Reflect Player: "))


  #"Select strategy:
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
        continue

    if p2 > 4:
        print("Sorry, you must select [1-4]: ")
        continue
    else:
        break


# Slecting 1 or 3 games
rounds = input('Enter for [s]ingle game or [f]ull game: ')
Game = Game(p2)
while True:
    if rounds == 's':
        Game.play_single()
        break
    elif rounds == 'f':
        Game.play_game()
        break
    else:
        print('Please select again')
        rounds = input('Enter [s] for a single'
                       'game and [f] for a full game: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Game = Game(p2)
```

There are a couple issues with this line.

1. Assigning the object created by `Game(p2)` to a `Game` variable *shadows* the `Game` class. This is unfortunate, as you won't be able to conveniently create `Game` objects later on. Better naming would give `game = Game(p2)`.
2. At that line, `p2` is an integer, because your code previously runs `p2 = int(input(...))`. Doing `Game(p2)` instantiates your `Game` object with an integer:

   ```
   def __init__(self, p2):
   self.p1 = HumanPlayer()
   self.p2 = p2                # now self.p2 is also an int
   ```

def play_round(self):
    move1 = self.p1.move()
    move2 = self.p2.move()      # calling some_int.move()
    ```
    The error correctly informs you that you're trying to call `.move` on an integer.  Something akin to `1.move` or `42.move`. There's no `.move` for integers though.

To solve this, use a different variable instead of `p2`, say... `choice`. That way, `p2` can stay a `dict` while the other variable, `choice`, can store the value entered.

```
# Selecting Opponent
while True:
    try:
        choice = int(input("Select the strategy "
                           "you want to play against:  "
                           "1 - Rock Player "
                           "2 - Random Player "
                           "3 - Cycle Player "
                           "4 - Reflect Player: "))

  #"Select strategy:
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
        continue

    if choice > 4:
        print("Sorry, you must select [1-4]: ")
        continue
    else:
        break

...

game = Game(p2[choice])  # since p2 is a dictionary with int keys and Player values
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Now it's giving me a nameError for p2?

game = Game(p2[choice])
NameError: name 'p2' is not defined

Comment: @Marcus I'll make some guesses here: 1) Check that the name of your file is `main.py`, else the `p2 = {...}` dictionary won't run under the if-block. Or 2) move the `p2 = {...}` outside of the if-block. Remove the `if __name__ == '__main__':` line completely.

Comment: 1. The name of my file is rps.py due to class requirements. 
2. I removed the if __name__ == '__main__': line to a nameError:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rps.py", line 77, in <module>
    class Game:
  File "rps.py", line 168, in Game
    game = game(p2[choice])
NameError: name 'game' is not defined
I played around with def Game(), but it doesn't seem that easy.

Comment: @Marcus Python is case-sensitive. `game = Game(p2[choice])` instead (that turns out to be what I put in my answer :P).